# Two jquery pluggin, the second to not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have one simple html file with a heading and two empty div

```
<h1>Blablabla.</h1>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

These two div have to be filled with some SVG contain generated with jquery SVG library (developped by Keith Wood). For that pupose, I included these scripts

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.svg.package-1.4.5/jquery.svg.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./myscript.svg.js"></script>
```

Then having a look at myscript.svg.js, it is a jquery code, with its ready function that attach plugin1 to div1 and plugin2 to div2 and call the publiv function generateSvg

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#div1').plugin1({'param': '5'});
  $('#div1').data('plugin1').generateSvg();
  $('#div2').plugin2();
  $('#div2').data('plugin2').generateSvg();
});
```

where plugin1 and plugin2 are two jquery plugin writing according to the boilerplate

```
(function($) {
  $.plugin1 = function(element, options) {
    var defaults = {
      param: '5'
      onFoo: function() {}
    }
    var plugin = this;
    plugin.settings = {}
    var $element = $(element), element = element;
    plugin.init = function() {
      plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    }
    plugin.generateSvg = function() {
      $element.svg();
      var svg = $element.svg('get');
      var defs = svg.defs();
      generate1Svg(svg);
    }
    var generate1Svg = function(svg) {
      ... etc ... 
    }
    plugin.init();
  }
  $.fn.plugin1 = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      if (undefined == $(this).data('plugin1')) {
        var plugin = new $.plugin1(this, options);
        $(this).data('plugin1', plugin);
      }
    });
  }
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
  $.plugin2 = function(element, options) {
    var defaults = {
    }
    var plugin = this;
    plugin.settings = {}
    var $element = $(element), element = element;
    plugin.init = function() {
      plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
alert('coucou');
    }
    plugin.generateSvg = function() {
alert('toto');
      $element.svg();
      var svg = $element.svg('get');
      var defs = svg.defs();
      generate2Svg(svg);
    }
    var generate2Svg = function(svg) {
      ... etc ... 
    }
    plugin.init();
  }
  $.fn.plugin2 = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      if (undefined == $(this).data('plugin2')) {
        var plugin = new $.plugin2(this, options);
        $(this).data('plugin2', plugin);
      }
    });
  }
})(jQuery);
```

My problem is the following : the svg drawing coded in plugin1 is well generated, but the svg drawing coded in plugin2 to not appear. Even the alert message do not appears.
And if I try to used plugin1 both for div1 and div2, it is not generated in div2
If I do not call the plugin1 for div1 and call plugin2 for div2, it is OK, the svg drawing coded in plugin2 appears

Comment: which ids do you speak abort ?

Comment: Here is my page 
http://byanhor.com/WargnierGenerator/WargnierSvgBaseCorsageEnfant5-9ans.html

And the js
http://byanhor.com/WargnierGenerator/WargnierSvgBaseCorsageEnfant5-9ans.svg.js

Comment: I do not use ids in the plugin2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a syntax error when your javascript runs:

```
resetSize is not defined on line 100.
```

That syntax error prevents any subsequent code from running and as it's at the end of the first div's content generation that works but the second div's code doesn't get to run. When you comment out the first div's code you stop the syntax error from occuring and the second div works.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot ! I was looking for so many post abort conflict between plugins...